# IIS MVC4 web site to serve file data on Linux machine?

Tags: asp.net, linux, iis-7

I have an IIS7 server where I'm building an administrative portal. This portal is required to read and write files that exist on a Linux machine.

What do I need to do to make this happen? Do I simply need to create a virtual directory from IIS pointing to the Linux directory with a service account (application pool identity)?

Comment: If downvoting, it would be considerate to at least mention why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Map a network drive to the linux machine and create a virtual dir pointing to the mapped drive.  Make sure that proper permissions are set.

Comment: Great! This is what I assumed I would do but just needed a second opinion on where I'd start. I would have just been missing the "mapped network drive."